# Run another version of Python using virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I apologize in advance if the question is dummy ,i use Python 3.2.3 on Windows xp ,now i need Python3.3.2 , but i can't remove Python 3.2.3 because i have many codes and packages need to be run by it.
I installed virtualenv to run two versions of Python in two different environments , but after that i didn't know what to do to run a code using Python 3.3.2 , here what i did:

```
C:\>virtualenv.exe env1
C:\>env1\Scripts\activate
```

now i don't know what to do after a folder was created its name env1 , i downloaded Python 3.3.2 and installed it in the same folder (env1) , is that correct ? then i try the following:

```
(env1) C:\>python3.3.2
```

I got the following :

```
'python3.3.2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  
operable program or batch file.
```

also i tried :

```
(env1) C:\>python python33
```

I got the following:

```
python: can't open file 'python33': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

As i mentioned , i stuck at this point , any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs.html should help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fast answer**: You can install the other version and say which one you want to use in your virtualenv using the flag -p

Install the new version as you did with the old. Say you have C:\Python32\ and C:\Python33\
folders. Now just call the command

```
virtualenv -p C:\Python33\python.exe venv
```

---

**Complete Answer**:

> I apologize in advance if the question is dummy ,i use Python 3.2.3 on Windows xp ,now i need Python3.3.2 , but i can't remove Python 3.2.3 because i have many codes and packages need to be run by it.
>   I installed virtualenv to run two versions of Python in two different environments , but after that i didn't know what to do to run a code using Python 3.3.2 , here what i did:
>
> C:>virtualenv.exe env1
>   C:>env1\Scripts\activate
>   now i don't know what to do after a folder was created its name env1 , i downloaded Python 3.3.2 and installed it in the same folder (env1) , is that correct ? then i try the following:

After the folder is created you activate the virtual environment with the activate script you just said above. Then you can use the python interpreter and check your version.

> (env1) C:>python3.3.2
>   I got the following :
>
> 'python3.3.2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. 
>   also i tried :

Just call python and check your version. You are using the sandbox created by virtualenv

> (env1) C:>python python33
>   I got the following:
>
> python: can't open file 'python33': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>   As i mentioned , i stuck at this point , any help will be very appreciated.

This is a weird call. You are trying to execute the python33 file as you do when you use

```
python hello_world.py
```

It is just saying that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: when i am calling python , it is going back to the default ( first ) version i had before which is python 3.2.3

Comment: did you create the virtualenv using the flag -p pointing to the python 3.3.2 ?

did you activate the environment? it shows in the prompt
(venv)C:\foo  the (venv) part says I'm using the venv environment

Comment: Ok , now i created a new environment venv , and type Python then i ended with the new version of Python which is 3.3.2 , that is good , but the question is how to run a code (lets say its name hello.py ) it is in the folder venv ?

Comment: doesn't matter where is the code. your environment is this one now. so just call python hello.py and it will execute using the python you had chosen. it means that you need to install all necessary third-party libraries that normally you use in your normal environment. you can install pip in venv and use pip to install everything. i recommend you to read http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't need virtualenv to use two different versions of python once you have installed Python 3.3.2 you can run a given script

```
C:\python33\python.exe script.py
```

or

```
C:\python32\python.exe script.py
```

since Python 3.3 was the last version you installed that is the version that windows will use when you double click on a script.

Comment: actually keeping Python 3.3.2 is going to bother me , since all my codes are with Python 3.2.3 , and i want to use virtualenv to get rid of keeping Python 3.3.2 or other Python versions , other point is that i tried to run both lines you posted above but i get that The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 0):

In my coding class, we added a new PATH (the path of the newest python) under environment variables. From there you can go to command prompt and type in:

```
C:\Users\Joe>python3
```

This is in my case.

1) To do this: go to your folder under C: that contains Python 3.3.2 (should be Python33 folder), rename the application named `python` to `python3` (write down or copy the path to the app).

2)Open the start menu, right click computer and click properties. A screen pops up, on the side it says "Advanced system settings". Another screen pops up and click environment variables.

3)Remember how I told you to write down that path? Under system variables, click the new button. Type the variable name as PATH and the variable value as

```
C:\Python33
```

Click OK, OK, OK. Open the start menu and get to the command prompt. Now just type in `python3`. You now should see something on the command prompt screen say something about Python 3.3.2.

You now have a line by line Python compiler. From this, you can build programs or type programs in notepad or Notepad++ and let the command prompt open it and run through it!

Good luck!!